# Writing a Stored procedure to search for matching values in columns with optional Input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**Requirement:**  To write stored Procedure(s) such that the values passed in stored procedures are matched against the values in columns in the table and then arranged with highest to lowest matching number of attributes.Then are inserted in a dynamically created temporary table inside the stored procedure.

Problem:

I have say 15-20 attributes that are matched against to confirm the suggestions made in response to record search. Basically, There is a table that stores Patients information and multiple parameters may be passed into the stored procedure to search through so that a Temporary table is created that suggests records in decreasing order of matching attributes.

To frame the basic structure, I tried with 3 attributes and respective stored procedures to match them which in turn are collectively called from a calling procedure based on the input parameter list which in turn creates the required temporary table.

Here is the SQL code(Just to give the gist of what I have tried so far):

But as a matter of fact it is, I realize this is way too naive to be used in a real time application which may require 80-90% of accuracy.So, what exactly can replace this technique for better efficiency?

```
Create Procedure NameMatch 
(
@Name nvarchar(20),
@PercentContribution nvarchar(4) OUT, @PatientName nvarchar(20) out
)
As
declare @temp int 
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(500)
   if Exists(select Name from dbo.PatientDetails where Name = @Name)
   Begin
   set @PatientName = @Name
   set @query = 'select * from dbo.PatientDetails where Name =' +  @Name
   set @temp = 0.1*100
   set @PercentContribution = @temp + '%'
   Execute(@query)
   Return
End

Create Procedure AgeMatch 
(
@Name nvarchar(20),
@Age int,
@PercentContribution nvarchar(4) OUT, @PatientName nvarchar(20) out
)
As
declare @temp int 
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(500)
   if Exists(select Name from dbo.PatientDetails where Name =@Name and Age = + @Age)
   Begin
   set @PatientName = @Name
   set @query = 'select * from dbo.PatientDetails where Name = ' + @Name + ' and Age = '+ @Age
   set @temp = 0.2*100
   set @PercentContribution = @temp + '%'
   Execute(@query)
   Return
End

Create Procedure Nationality 
(
@Name nvarchar(20),
@Age int,
@Nation nvarchar(10),
@PercentContribution nvarchar(4) OUT, @PatientName nvarchar(20) out
)
As
declare @temp int 
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(500)
   if Exists(select Name from dbo.PatientDetails where Name = @Name and Age = @Age and Nationality = @Nation )
   Begin
   set @PatientName = @Name
   set @query = 'select * from dbo.PatientDetails where Name = ' + @Name + ' and Age  = '+ @Age + ' and Nationality = ' + @Nation
   set @temp = 0.3*100
   set @PercentContribution = @temp + '%'
   Execute(@query)
   Return
End

create procedure CallingProcedure
(
@Name nvarchar(20),
@Age int = null,
@Nation nvarchar(10)=  null
)
As 
declare @PercentMatch nvarchar(4)
Begin
create table #results(PatientName nvarchar(30), PercentMatch nvarchar(4))
if(@Nation IS NOT NULL)
Insert into #results exec Nationality @Nation, @Name output, @PercentMatch output
else if(@Age is not Null)
Insert into #results exec AgeMatch @Age, @Name output, @PercentMatch output
else
Insert into #results exec NameMatch @Name, @Name output, @PercentMatch output
End
```

Comment: Which dbms? (The syntax is not ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: looks like T-SQL? SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: @jarlh : Possible, though everything mentioned above did compile but I have been trying it with bits and pieces of knowledge so mistakes are possible ;)

Comment: Take a look at this article. It explains how to deal with this type of query and keep the performance from getting too slow. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside nuances of stored procedure syntax, given parameters 1-n that if not null should match columns 1-n and the results sorted by highest number of matches first, a dynamic query is not needed - plain SQL can do it.

```
select *
from patient
where @param1 is null or column1 = @param1
or @param2 is null or column2 = @param2
...
or @paramN is null or columnN = @paramN
order by if(column1 = @param1, 1, 0)
    + if(column2 = @param2, 1, 0)
    ...
    + if(columnN = @paramN, 1, 0) desc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this concise yet efficient solution. A simple query though, (column2 = @param2, 1, 0)    , What is the significance/effect of 1 and 0 as the added parameters?

Comment: The `if` function has the form `if (condition, value if true, value if false)`, which returns `1` if the there was a match on that column, zero if not. The entire chain of ifs counts how many matches there were.